# How to order by associated model count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

City model:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :angels
  def angel_count
    angels.size
  end
end
```

Angel model:

```
class Angel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city, :counter_cache => true
  attr_accessible :city_id
end
```

I able to access the `angel_count` method through the rails_admin list action, however it won't allow me to change the order direction like the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `counter_cache` wrong way. Do you have angels_count column in cities table? If not, add the column and run migration. You should be able to sort by this column.

Comment: Is there no way to order by the `angel_count` method I have? I would rather not have to create a new column with static values.

Comment: The `angel_count` method generates separate SQL query for every object (city). To properly sort 1000 cities and display 10 ones (on current page) the application will have to make 1001 queries, allocate memory for 1000 objects. Compare with one query and 10 objects if you're using counter_cache. This is why auto-admin gems usually do not allow sorting by instance method, not DB column.